# Restore chrome password from my old hdd

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, password

You need to somehow pull out the passwords from the Google Chrome profile.

I do not have the ability to boot from it, but I know all the logins and passwords from the accounts in it for logging in to system and the Google account.

It left unsynchronized account passwords in the Google profile. I need to get them somehow.

Tried through sqlite viewing tools, there passwords ciphered.
I tried to connect it as an external drive to a new laptop, but the system did not boot, I decided not to do any more manipulations with it.

I don't know if I'm right that only booting from an old PC would allow them to be restored?

Is it possible to decrypt a hashed password with any files from that disk + account passwords?

Comment: Have you tried copying the profile files to a different computer running on a blank install of Chrome (with no existing profiles)?

Comment: Also, copying is safer because you're not manipulating data on the original disk.

Comment: the passwords are then in a broken form "decrypted"